# .htaccess Rewriting to a php file and query

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've been trying to accomplish this type of redirection with .htaccess yet I cannot figure out the correct way of doing so (after searching google for a while):

```
test.example.com/more -> example.com/test.php?o=more
```

I tried to do the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.example\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.example\.com/(.*)$ $1.php?o=$2 [L,NC,QSA]
```

I'm not very understanding on how .htaccess fully works so any help with this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ /%1.php?o=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: The subdomain aspect of it is working but the query isn't going through (just leaving a blank o= according to php).

Comment: Ah it should have been `$1`, fixed it now.